# problema con position relative y absolute en react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

tengo una vista con problema de superposicion de elementos debido al position relative y absolute. El codigo es el siguiente:

```
<View style={{position: 'relative'}}>
  <View style={{position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0}}></View>
</View>

<Text>lorem ipsum</Text>
```

[image: problema de superposicion]

Como se ve el texto Routine page esta por arriba del video, cuando deberia estar debajo.
Alguna idea de como solucionarlo?

Saludos!

Comment: Que tal, ¿Podrías describirme un poco más cómo debería verse el diseño de tu pantalla para poder ayudarte?

Comment: La pregunta no es muy clara, pero si quieres que estés por debajo en el eje Z, trabaja con z-index. Si quieres que esté por debajo en el eje Y, quita top: 0 y utiliza bottom: 0.
Si no es ninguna, por favor, vuelve a redactar la pregunta.

Comment: quien es el padre de esos 2 el texto y la view padre? relative en web hace que todos esten en el flujo del padre y puedan moverse como un offset con left top...etc.